# initializer_list combined with other parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Suppose I have a class which takes a parameter of type `T` and a collection of parameters of type `U` in the constructor. 
The following solution works:

```
struct Q
{
    Q(T t, std::initializer_list<U> us);
};
```

Creating an instance of this class would then be:

`Q q {t1, {u1, u2, u3, u4} };`

But this looks kind of unclean to me. Is there a better solution than this one?

Comment: Do you mean you find it ugly to look at, or do you doubt that it is covered by the language standard?

Comment: It just seems unclean to me, compared to when only a collection is needed: `Q q {u1, u2, u3, u4}`, and wanted to know if a better solution exists. I edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is variadic templates (c++11 feature).

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct T {};
struct U {};

class Q {
  public:
    template <class ...ArgTypes>
    Q(T t, ArgTypes... args) : Q(t, {args...}) {}
  private:
    Q(T t, std::initializer_list<U> us) {}
};

int main() {
  T t1;
  U u1, u2, u3, u4;
  Q {t1, u1, u2, u3, u4};
}
```

It's still typesafe - only structures of type `U` are allowed.

Comment: You introduced me to another C++11 concept -- [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor). Very cool!